# How do I categorize a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm looking to categorize/sort a list by matching certain strings. I previously couldn't find a solution so hopefully this way is easier.

Example list:

```
[A]
The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree
Apples grow on deciduous trees which are large if grown from seed
Apples are an important ingredient in many desserts, such as apple pie
Puréed apples are generally known as apple sauce
A banana is an edible fruit produced by several kinds of large plants
Worldwide, there is no sharp distinction between "bananas" and "plantains"
The term "banana" is also used as the common name for the plants
Orange is the colour of saffron, pumpkins and apricots
The colour orange is named after the appearance of the ripe orange fruit
In ancient Egypt, artists used an orange mineral pigment called realgar
Apple, orange and banana smoothie
Eating an orange and banana exceed allowable sugar intake
Kale or borecole (Brassica oleracea Acephala Group) is a vegetable
Until the end of the Middle Ages, kale was one of the most common green vegetables
```

Strings being looked for and how they'll be categorized (case insensitive):

```
Apple = Apple
Apple Pie = Dessert
Banana = Banana
Orange = Orange
(anything not categorized) = Vegetables
(multiple found strings) = Multiple --> if this isn't possible it's fine
```

Here's what the column next to the list might say:

```
[B]
Apple
Apple
Pie
Apple
Banana
Banana
Banana
Orange
Orange
Orange
Multiple
Multiple
Vegetables
Vegetables
```

And then I'd just use sorting/filter. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're up to here.

Comment: I'm afraid Excel is not capable of doing the job directly.  If you know VBA you can give a try; otherwise other tools may be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In. It takes a few steps to get there but no code or changes to your input data structure are required.

I've built a prototype which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - searching for a list of keywords and categorizing" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Basically my technique was to build a preliminary Query to load the list of categories and assign a dummy merge key, then Merge that against the text to be searched using a dummy merge key.  This produces a row for each input row x each category. Then I calculated the category using the Text.Contains function, and finally used a Group By to return to the original set of rows.

At that point you have a normalised table which is ideal for exploration by filtering or using a Pivot Table and/or Pivot Chart.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you want it to be dynamic AND hieractical (apple pie takes precident over apple), makes it a bit tough, but if you're willing to have it statically programmed you could do something like this:

```
Row 1 - Your search text
Row 2 - Your result text

B1=Apple
B2=Apple
B3=If(Len($A2)>LEN(SUBTITUTE(LOWER($A2),LOWER(B$1),"")),B$2,"")
C1=Apple Pie
C2=Deserts
D1=Orange
D2=Orange
Drag B3 across and down
```

What you're doing is substituting instances of "apple" with nothing and then counting the letters to see if there are less than the original.  Normally this is a case sensitive opperation, but I've used the lowercased both the texts I'm comparing first. This will output the result text in each column if there was a hit for that columns search text.

To encorperate the hiarchy you could change the B's column to IF(LEN(C2)>0,"",NORMAL FORMULA), so that the column won't say APPLE if column C already has a value.  NORMAL FORMULA just being the formula for B3 from above.

Then you could use a counta to measure how many hits you have

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:D2)=0,"Vegitables",IF(COUNTA(B2:D2)>1,"Multiple",B2&C2&D2))
```

If there are 0 matches, vegitables, if multiple, then multiple, otherwise you'll only have one field filled in so you can get your final answer by concatinating the results.

Also, I did come up with a formula that just takes a dynamic list and figures out how many hits you have.  This is an array function, so you'll have to type it in without the {} and then instead of hitting enter hit ctrl+shift+enter

```
{=SUM(--(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2),LOWER($F$1:$F$6),""))>0))}
```

This fails though as it would could 2 for anything that has "apple pie" in it since it has both apple and pie, but wins as it can work off a dynamic list provided in column F.